# How to generate a given number of Controls at run-time?

Tags: c#, winforms

The task is as follows, the form already has a TextBox that will accept numbers from 2 to 4 and after you have written the number and pressed enter, RadioButtons will be generated under the TextBox as many as you have written in the TextBox

Here is my attempt:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    RadioButton radioButton;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.KeyDown += Enter;
        Controls.Add(textBox1);
    }

    private void Enter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            int radioButtonCount;
            if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out radioButtonCount))
            {
                CreateRadioButtons(radioButtonCount);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void CreateRadioButtons(int count)
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();

        int maxButtonsPerRow = 4;
        int buttonsInCurrentRow = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
            radioButton.Text = "RadioButton " + (i + 1);
            radioButton.Location = new Point();

            this.Controls.Add(radioButton);

            buttonsInCurrentRow++;
            if (buttonsInCurrentRow >= maxButtonsPerRow)
            {
                buttonsInCurrentRow = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be improved by qualifying with `OfType<RadioButton()` when querying the `Controls` collection for buttons to dispose, and supplying a `Name` property to the generated buttons to additionally qualify the intended targets for disposal with precision.

Since your spec states that the number of buttons should be between 2 and 4, consider using a `NumericUpDown` control where you can set min and max values (something I haven't limited here...). If in the future you find there are more buttons than will fit in a single row, integer division works for calculating row and the modulo operator is good for column.

[image: screenshot]

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        numericUpDown.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            foreach (
                var genTextBox in
                Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()                      // Only Radio Buttons
                .Where(_ => _.Name.IndexOf("radioButtonGen") == 0)  // Only matching name
                .ToArray())                                         // Insulate from collection changes
            {
                genTextBox.Dispose();   // Properly dispose of buttons handles
            }
            var count = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown.Value);
            for (var index = 0; index < count; index++)
            {
                var row = index / 4;
                var column = index % 4;
                var radioButtonGen = new RadioButton
                {
                    Name = $"radioButtonGen{index + 1}",
                    Text = $"RadioButton{index + 1}",
                    Location = new Point
                    {
                        X = numericUpDown.Left + (column * (MARGIN + WIDTH)),
                        Y = numericUpDown.Bottom + ((row + 1) * MARGIN) + (row * HEIGHT),
                    },
                    Size = new Size(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
                };
                Controls.Add(radioButtonGen);
            }
        };
        numericUpDown.KeyDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if(e.KeyData == Keys.Return)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;  // Avoid unwanted alert sounds
            }
        };
    }
    const int
        MAX_BUTTONS_PER_ROW = 4,
        MARGIN = 10,
        HEIGHT = 24,
        WIDTH = 180;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `CreateRadioButtons` method, you are using `this.Controls.Clear()`, which removes all controls from the form, including `textBox1`. This is probably not what you want. Instead, you should clear only the previously created radio buttons.

```
private void CreateRadioButtons(int count)
{
    // Clear previous radio buttons
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is RadioButton)
        {
            Controls.Remove(control);
        }
    }

    int startY = textBox1.Bottom + 10; // Position below the textBox
    int spacing = 30; // Spacing between radio buttons

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton
        {
            Text = "RadioButton " + (i + 1),
            Location = new Point(10, startY + i * spacing)
        };

        this.Controls.Add(radioButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the wrong way to remove the controls because you are iterating over the collection while removing them.  Unless they are going to come back, it would be better to dispose of them instead, as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CreateRadioButtons()` method first create a Panel or GroupBox and then add the RadioButtons to this container. When you clear the RadioButtons then just clear in the container e.g.

```
pnlButtons.Controls.Clear();
```

Comment: Note: clearing does not dispose of those controls.

Comment: @LarsTech: Useful reminder. The `Dispose()` method must be used to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your own `List<RadioButton>` and clear the previous ones before creating new ones:

```
private List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new List<RadioButton>();

private void Enter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        int radioButtonCount;
        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out radioButtonCount))
        {
            CreateRadioButtons(radioButtonCount);
        }
    }
}

private void CreateRadioButtons(int count)
{
    // clear out any previous ones and empty the list
    foreach(RadioButton rb in  radioButtons)
    {
        rb.Dispose();
    }
    radioButtons.Clear();

    int maxButtonsPerRow = 4;
    int buttonsInCurrentRow = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
        radioButtons.Add(radioButton); // <-- add to your List
        radioButton.Text = "RadioButton " + (i + 1);
        radioButton.Location = new Point();

        this.Controls.Add(radioButton);

        buttonsInCurrentRow++;
        if (buttonsInCurrentRow >= maxButtonsPerRow)
        {

            buttonsInCurrentRow = 0;
        }
    }
}
```